# What is the Swachh Bharat Mission doing to reduce pollution in India?

Tags: india, environmental-policy

Does the [Swachh Bharat Abhiyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swachh_Bharat_Abhiyan) (Clean India Mission) have any solution to India's problem of pollution?

The primary focus seems to be on building isolated toilet complexes or units in rural areas. The government even advertises the effectiveness of the scheme on the number of toilets built. But most of these toilets are just single room units in villages, without plumbing or water supply. So people have resorted to using these toilets as homes and shops.

Is there any other projects Swachh Bharat Mission is involved in ? What should be the focus of the cleanliness mission?

Comment: I don't think this is primarily opinion based, as someone voted.

Comment: The question as written would be answered by the Wikipedia article linked by it. The tone seems to imply that this is not actually a honest question but rather a complaint about the SBA not being effective enough. If the author of the question wants to know some politically relevant factoid which isn't stated in the article linked in the question, it should ask for that explicitly.

Comment: So, how would I form a question, "to know some politically relevant factoid which isn't stated in the article " ?